# Python SciPy giving error with pip install scipy

Tags: python, compiler-errors, scipy, pip

```
C:\PY27\Scripts>pip install --no-cache-dir scipy
Collecting scipy
c:\py27\lib\site-   
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:318: 
SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name 
Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may 
cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause 
validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve 
this. For more information, see 
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.

SNIMissingWarning
c:\py27\lib\site-  
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: 
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This 
prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain 
SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to 
solve this. For more information, see 

   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

InsecurePlatformWarning
Downloading scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz (13.1MB)
100% |################################| 13.1MB 239kB/s
Installing collected packages: scipy
Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
Complete output from command c:\py27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\puneet~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-
qvvewa\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\puneet~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-icoko3-record\install-record.txt --
single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\py27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\py27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\py27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\py27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: 
Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-
builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
  pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\py27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\py27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\puneet~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-
qvvewa\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "c:\users\puneet~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-
qvvewa\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in 
setup
    config = configuration()
  File "c:\users\puneet~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-
qvvewa\scipy\setup.py", line 335, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, 
in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, 
in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, 
in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, 
in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, 
in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, 
in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\py27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,  
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\puneet~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-
qvvewa\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\puneet~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-icoko3-record\install-record.txt --
single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
c:\users\puneet~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qvvewa\scipy\
```

I am trying to install through pip the scipy package.
Running on Windows 10 64 bit simpl Python 2.7.3 no anaconda.
Can you please tell what is going wrong while install package scipy?

Many Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I suggest you could start with upgrading your python, the current `2.7` is `2.7.13`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned, try with .whl

You should download the right file from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
Then cd to where you've downloaded your scipy_some_version.whl and

```
    pip install scipy_some_version.whl
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just `pip install` scipy on Windows. Use Gohlke wheels or Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows does not have any package manager analogous to that in Linux, you cannot just use `pip install <packagename>`, so installing one of the scientific Python distributions mentioned at [Installing the SciPy Stack](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) is preferred. However, if that is not an option, Christoph Gohlke provides [pre-built Windows installers for many Python packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), including all of the core SciPy stack, which work extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and it turned out that scipy was not happy with numpy.
Then I used "conda intsall scipy"   and it intalled the required version without any error.

For anyone using windows anaconda installation is strongly recommended. If any old version of python is required then one can create virtual env and install the required version of python.