# Error in installing scipy on Windows 10

Tags: python, scipy

When I attempt to install scipy on Windows 10, it fails

```
>Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ashima\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-1wbaof6j\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ashima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mea6a2r6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\ashima\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\ashima\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\ashima\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\ashima\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
  pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\ashima\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\ashima\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ashima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1wbaof6j\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\ashima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1wbaof6j\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\ashima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1wbaof6j\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found


>Command "c:\users\ashima\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ashima\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-1wbaof6j\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ashima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mea6a2r6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ashima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1wbaof6j\scipy\
```

Comment: Sounds like you should use pip, based on "install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`". We don't know what you tried that produced this.

Comment: I used the command - pip install scipy

Comment: It's tough work on Windows. Instead, you can first download `numpy + mkl` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install the `.whl` (I think you need `pip install wheel` first, then open cmd in the same directory as the downloaded file and do `pip install the_file_name`. Also you can get the other scientific programs from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing SciPy with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240720/python-scipy-giving-error-with-pip-install-scipy/42247760#42247760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for your answers.

But I found a better solution to this.
My problem got resolved by downloading numpy wheel file, scipy wheel file and the scikit-learn wheel file and installing it the same way as we install any other python file.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error when I installed scipy.  I have found it much easier to just install it using Anaconda.  The installer is here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Caution: it will also install other python libs related to data science such as NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, Matplotlib, and Jupyter.  A full list by python version is here: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs#python-3-6

I installed this after having python already installed, and there was no issue.

Sorry for not answering your question directly, but this will deliver you scipy and many more goodies!

Comment: "Sorry for not answering your question directly" I'd argue that between my comment and your answer, they are the only valid ways to fix the OP's issue. The scientific stack does not like Windows at all.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for backing me up on this, @roganjosh .  I will have to try what your comment suggests next time I need to install, especially if I need a leaner stack.